# How to countdown to milliseconds in UTC

Tags: java, android

I'm using an api which fetches all upcoming movies and all dates in the api are stored in milliseconds, when I try to countdown from today's date to the movie's release date, the countdown is in my local timezone. For example, I'm in the east coast and when the countdown reaches 8 PM it counts as a new day and the number of days left decrements

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, this was the countdown when it was around 9 PM in the east coast, so at 8 PM it would have been 24 hours left, how can I change this? Of course I want it to reset the day at midnight, not at 8 PM. Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
  public long getMillisInGMT(long date) {
    // We don't care what date format we're going to format to
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String formatted = formatter.format(new Date(date));
    try {
        return formatter.parse(formatted).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

public void initCountdown(_Release release) {
    long releaseDate = release.getDate();
    long timeTillRelease = getMillisInGMT(releaseDate) - getMillisInGMT(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    mCountdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeTillRelease, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // 1 sec = 1000 millis
            long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            long minutes = seconds / 60;
            long hours = minutes / 60;
            long days = hours / 24;
            mDaysTxt.setText(String.valueOf(days));
            mHoursText.setText(String.valueOf(hours % 24));
            mMinutesText.setText(String.valueOf(minutes % 60));
            mSecondsText.setText(String.valueOf(seconds % 60));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mHeaderReleasesTitle.setText("Released on");
            mOutNowTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mCountdownLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
    mCountdownTimer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure where your error is coming from, but I know that I've run into a lot of problems using the Date and Calendar libraries. By far the best time library out there is the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html) library. If it were me, I'd replace the library and see if that fixed things before troubleshooting further.

To get the current UTC (GMT) time you would use the DateTime library like below:

```
DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

To convert the Release millis to UTC you would use the DateTime library like below:

```
new DateTime(dateInMillis).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but I can't tell you how many odd issues I ran into while using the Date and Calendar libraries. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html) fixes most issues. It's an amazing library.

Comment: Really interesting, I'll try it out and tell you how it goes, thank you

Comment: Why not `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` since java 8 already introduced these in [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), which actually has most of the frequently used features in Joda-time. Why bother introducing another library since java already supports it.